# Не получается привязать QLabel к элементу в QListWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, drag-n-drop, qlistwidget

Идея заключается в том, чтобы создать `QListWidget` с полями, 
которые можно переносить мышкой между друг другом.

В написанном ниже коде это реализовано, но проблема в том, что когда пользователь перетягивает элемент в другое место, 
то переносится только один итем из этого списка (одна строка). 
`QLabel`, который должен был быть привязан к итему, остаётся на месте.

```
import datetime
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class PageMarks(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.checktime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.page_additional = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.page_additional.setObjectName("page_additional")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.page_additional)
        self.page_additional.setStyleSheet(
            "border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 1em;")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.page_additional)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            ' ', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: rgba(79, 87, 96, 1)")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.font = self.label_content.font()
        self.font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(self.font)

        self.contentgrid = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.label_content)
        self.contentgrid.setContentsMargins(15, 15, 15, 15)

        self.manipulation_grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.manipulation_grid.setContentsMargins(15, 15, 15, 15)
        self.contentgrid.addLayout(self.manipulation_grid)

# Fonts
        self.fontArial = QFont('Arial', 14, 75)
        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Play-Bold.ttf")
        self.fontPlay = QFont("Play", 14)
# Fields Block
        self.fieldgrid = QVBoxLayout()
        self.fieldgrid.setContentsMargins(0, 40, 0, 10)
        self.fieldgrid.setSpacing(2)
        self.manipulation_grid.addLayout(self.fieldgrid, 0, 0)

        self.generatorList()

    def generatorList(self):
        self.list = QListWidget(self.label_content)
        self.list.setMinimumSize(1000, 400)
        self.list.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.list.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.list.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.list.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)

        self.item = QListWidgetItem()
        self.item.setSizeHint(QSize(1000, 50))
        # self.item.setIcon(icon)
        self.list.addItem(self.item)
        self.item.setBackground(QColor(120, 180, 60))
        self.item.setForeground(QColor(20, 80, 160))

        self.field = QLabel()
        self.field.setObjectName("index 1")
        self.field.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.field.setMinimumSize(1000, 50)
        self.grid = QHBoxLayout(self.field)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.labelImg = QLabel()
        icon_image_url = "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/478/PNG/512/slack_47017.png"
        self.icon = QImage()
        self.icon.loadFromData(requests.get(icon_image_url).content)
        scaledImg = self.icon.scaled(
            40, 40, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.labelImg.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.icon))
        self.labelImg.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(scaledImg))
        self.grid.addWidget(self.labelImg)

        self.mark = QLabel("Item 6")
        self.mark.setFont(self.fontPlay)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.mark)
        self.btn = QPushButton('')
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton:hover { 
                background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:8, x2:4, y2:0, stop:1 transparent, stop:0 rgba(55, 227, 32, 1));
                border: 0px solid;
                border-radius: 8px;
            }
            QPushButton:!hover { 
                background-color: transparent; 
                border: 0px solid; 
            }
        """)
        self.btn.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.btn.setMinimumHeight(50)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.markInput = QLineEdit()
        self.markInput.setFont(self.fontPlay)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.markInput)

        self.list.setItemWidget(self.item, self.field)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PageMarks()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Куда должны перемещаться строки?

Comment: В тот же контейнер. То есть перетаскиванием мыши пользователь по задумке может перетасовывать строки, изменять их положение в списке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #6EBF8B;')
        
        self.iconLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)         
        self.iconLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80) 
        self.iconLabel.setMaximumSize(80, 80) 
        
        self.textLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()                

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit() 
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: #B85C38; color: white')
        
        self.layout  = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textLabel, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1)

    def setTextLabel(self, text):
        self.textLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath).scaled(80, 80, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return True
            
        widget_img = self.grab()                       
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(widget_img)
        painter.setCompositionMode(
            painter.CompositionMode_DestinationIn
        )
        painter.fillRect(widget_img.rect(), QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 127))
        painter.end()
        data = QtCore.QMimeData()
        data.setText('')
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(data)
        drag.setPixmap(widget_img)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)


class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('''font-size: 25px''')

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def add_widget(self, widget=None, index=-1):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())
        
        currentRow = self.currentRow()
        if index == currentRow:
            return

        if index < 0:
            self.addItem(item)
        else:
            self.insertItem(index, item)
            
        self.setItemWidget(item, widget)
        
        if currentRow > index and index != -1:
            currentRow += 1 
        it = self.takeItem(currentRow)
        del it                                               

    def add_btn(self, widget, txt='', index=-1):
        if not txt or not isinstance(txt, basestring):
            btn_name = 'Button Item {:02d}'.format(self.count() + 1)
        else:
            btn_name = txt
        
        if index < 0:
            self.add_widget(widget)
        else:
            self.add_widget(widget, index)        
        
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        drop_index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            widget = event.source()
            self.add_btn(widget, index=drop_index)                
        super(ListWidget, self).dropEvent(event)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)        
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("""
            border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 1em;
            background-color: rgba(255, 87, 96, 255);
        """)

        dataWidget = [
            ('Item 1', 'D:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg'), 
            ('Item 2', 'Ok.png'),
            ('Item 3', 'D:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'),
         ]

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        for item, icon in dataWidget:
            customQWidget = QCustomQWidget(self)   
            customQWidget.setTextLabel(item)
            customQWidget.setIcon(icon)
            listWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
            listWidgetItem.setSizeHint(customQWidget.sizeHint())
            self.listWidget.addItem(listWidgetItem)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(listWidgetItem, customQWidget)
        
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet('''
            font-size: 30px;
            background-color: rgba(79, 187, 196, 100);
        ''')
        self.listWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.listWidget.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.listWidget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.listWidget.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]